# most effecient way to order an array by sub elements?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array.

```
$array[0] = array(1, 8, 2);    
$array[1] = array(5, 6, 15);
$array[2] = array(-8, 2, 1025);
```

I am wondering what the most efficient way to order the parent array by a particular property of it's sub array. For example, I want to put them in ascending order of $sub_array[1], so the parent array would be ordered 2,1,0.

Comment: I didn't get what you're asking. ELaborate.

Comment: It's hard to put in words. I am trying to order an array by values within nested arrays.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701855/how-do-i-sort-a-php-array-by-an-element-nested-inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and its cousins have variations where you can supply your own sorting callback function: [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) (which maintains indexes), and [`uksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) (which sorts on the keys. You'll have to create your own sorting callback to do what you want to do here.

```
function sort_by_subarray($a, $b)
{
  // $a and $b are elements of $array that are being compared against
  // each other to be sorted

  if (!isset($a[1]) || !isset($b[1]))
  {
    // Do something if $a[1] or $b[1] is undefined
    // Your question doesn't define what the behaviour here should be
  }
  else
  {
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) return 0;     // the elements are the same
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;  // otherwise, sort from lowest to highest
  }
}

$array = array(
  array(1, 8, 2),
  array(5, 6, 15),
  array(-8, 2, 1025)
);
uasort($array, "sort_by_subarray");

/* Results in:
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -8
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1025
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 15
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 2
        )

)
*/
```

Note that my function will sort two subarrays as being equal if $subarray[1] is equal, so if you want to be more specific, you can add more rules for when `$a[1] == $b[1]`.

Comment: almost there, but I need something that will sort by one specific value with the sub_array - So if array[1]->sub_array[2]  >  array[2]->sub_array[2] then array[1] trumps array [2]

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: that's what my sorting function should be doing (see the results). Unless I misunderstood something?

Comment: Is there any good resource for understanding the custom callback functions better?

Comment: A custom callback function is just a function that you write yourself that you pass to another function. The manual page for usort should help.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php and write a callback function that implements the sort condition you want.