# Sorting data from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I've decoded a JSON result from a server request and now need to sort based on the [name] field from the array. The deserialized code looks like this (snippet)

```
Array
(
[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [houseTypes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [2] => 4
                    )

                [id] => 1
                [name] => Aberdeen
                [isLive] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [houseTypes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2
                        [1] => 3
                        [2] => 4
                    )

                [id] => 2
                [name] => Aberystwyth
                [isLive] =>
```

There is no guarantee that the data coming down from the server will by alphabetical, so I need to sort based on the name.

I've tried using sort, assort and ksort, but none are showing correctly.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: use foreach loop and then try ksort

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701855/how-do-i-sort-a-php-array-by-an-element-nested-inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it simple,
try this:

```
function cmp($a,$b)
{
    if($a['name'] == $b['name'])
        return 0;
    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($yourarray['items'],'cmp');
print_r($yourarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with usort.See this http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
 function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
            $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    asort($b);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
            $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}
$users = subval_sort($users,'name');
```